# Is it possible to only call a method if a condition is met inside an extension?

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

I have the following working code:

```
var cached = Cache.Get(object);
var load = (cached.HasValue)
   ? cached.Value()
   : await GetLoad(object);
```

Is it possible to make that into an extension?
I've tried the following:

```
public async static Task<T> Else<T>(this Result<T> result, Task<T> fn)
{
    if (result.HasValue)
    {
        return result.Value;
    }
    return await fn;
}
// Called like this:
var cached = Cache.Get(object).Else(GetLoad(object));
```

But the problem is it ALWAYS calls the `GetLoad(object)` regardless of the condition being met or not.

What I need is for the `GetLoad(object)` to ONLY be called if `result.HasValue` is false.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `.Else(() => GetLoad(object))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of taking `Task<T>` as an argument, you need to take a `Func<Task<T>>`.

i.e.

```cs
public async static Task<T> Else<T>(this Result<T> result, Func<Task<T>> fn)
{
    if (result.HasValue)
    {
        return result.Value;
    }
    return await fn();
}
// Called like this:
var cached = Cache.Get(object).Else(() => GetLoad(object));
```

With your existing code, `GetLoad(object)` is resolved so that its result can be passed to `Else` as a parameter. By passing a func instead you delay execution until the result is needed.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! This was doing my head in!!